# Stack level too deep in activesupport callbacks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, stack-trace, activesupport

I am getting the `SystemStackError` in a Rails 3 app.

All the information I have is useless one line of a stacktrace (taken from the log):

```
SystemStackError (stack level too deep):
  activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:409
```

So the question is how do I **see the full stack trace**?

**NOTE**: I don't care about *why* this happens, all I want is to see is **where** it happens.

Using: Rails 3.2.3, Unicorn.

Thanks.

Comment: Found [this page](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/issues/349). Not sure if it helps.

Comment: A company frequently featured in the Careers 2.0 sidebar [claims to give good visibility into the details of running applications](http://newrelic.com/ruby) -- perhaps they have tools that can periodically dump stack traces for you and catch a deep one "in action" before it leads to an error?

Comment: @Riateche that problem happens in Rails < 3.2.3. I'm on 3.2.3.

Comment: @sarnold, I am not going to add another stack of tools to see the stack trace. Something must be cutting it off and want to find what that is.

Comment: do you have a .save method anywhere in your before/after save filter?

Comment: @djd, probably, but it is not the question. I've already fixed it. The question is how to know where it happens (full stack trace).

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13089936/tracking-logging-activerecord-callbacks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's pretty complex code in lib/active_support/callbacks.rb, but it looks like it is applying various callbacks: :before, :after, :around, to be precise.

You might try placing an old fashioned "puts before #{name}" before line 426 and seeing what you get.

Equally, could be that the entire stack trace is inside the rails stack, and it is being filtered out by the default backtrace_filter. Setting that backtrace_filter off might let you see the stack and get a debugging clue. See config/initializers/backtrace_silencers.rb and uncomment:

> Rails.backtrace_cleaner.remove_silencers!

Answer (score 5):

If you update an active record in it's before_save or after_save, it will keep on looping....
Also, if you have validates_associated on both ends of an association.

Here is an example of how a `before_save` callback can create a loop:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  def before_save
    self.update_attribute(:bar, 'badidea')
  end
end
```

Comment: Hi Andrew, would you mind giving an example of how exactly you could "update an active record in its before_save"? Thank you!

Comment: Kinda hard in a comment to put in code, something like this: class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base; def before_save; self.update_attribute(:bar, 'badidea'); end; end

Answer (score 1):

For those that are able to upgrade to Ruby 2.2, you should get a much more descriptive stack trace as a result of work done by Nobu on MRI (https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/6216).  Switching to JRuby would also give a much deeper stack.

Answer (score 0):

This is a shot in the dart but I hit something like this once when I had circular references in my `validates_associated`'s

Comment: Yeah, it is the shot in the dark. And no, nothing to do with the validation. I know what causes it. I don't care about *WHY* it happens. I want to know *where* (so want to see the callstack).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue.  Controller Actions that were skipping before/after filters would eventually error out with the error

```
SystemStackError (stack level too deep):
  activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:409
```

Best I can figure is that the way Rails adds/removes methods to the callback stack would create an error under heavy stress.

These are API calls, so I moved them to a separate controller that inherited from ActionController::Base, removing the need to skip filters.  This solved my issue.  ApplicationController::Metal may be a better choice depending on which features you need.

I know the asker was not concerned with why, but I figure other Rails Developers might run across the same issue, and none of the logging suggestions above returned a valid stack trace for me.