# How to list all callbacks that were executed in a .save operation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In a model in my codebase, there is a callback that are not being execute when I update a record, only when I create it.
I suspect that this is because another callback are returning false and halting the callbacks' chain.
That is why I want to know which callbacks are being executed in a determined operation (In this case, `update`).
Is it possible to list these callbacks?
I couldn't find how in https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v4.2/active_record_callbacks.html.

Comment: What do you mean by "list them"?

Comment: A list like the list of the methods returned by `public_methods`

Comment: `public_methods` returns an `array` of the public methods accessible to *obj*. It does not provide any information about which, if any, of these methods have been accessed. So, do you want to know which `callbacks` are accessible (which is in the docs you linked to). Or, do you want to know which `callbacks` are accessed (executed; called) during a given request-response cycle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a gem for this [RailsCallbackLog](https://github.com/jaredbeck/rails-callback_log)

Author already posted it here, in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13089936/tracking-logging-activerecord-callbacks) question (second answer) .

An example: for this code 
 `Mechanic.first.save`  (`Mechanic` is just an ActiveRecord model)
gem with default settings printed this

```
Callback: validate_associated_records_for_mechanics_games
Callback: validate_associated_records_for_games
Callback: _ensure_no_duplicate_errors
Callback: before_save_collection_association
Callback: #<ActiveSupport::Callbacks::Conditionals::Value:0x000000000b7736d8>
Callback: autosave_associated_records_for_mechanics_games
Callback: #<ActiveSupport::Callbacks::Conditionals::Value:0x000000000b6eba08>
Callback: autosave_associated_records_for_games
Callback: #<ActiveSupport::Callbacks::Conditionals::Value:0x000000000b6f1890>
Callback: after_save_collection_association
Callback: print_hello
```

Last callback `print_hello` was custom, defined for this test case, so gem shows both default and custom callbacks.

Answer (score -2):

This callback works when using the upgrade method:

", on: :update"

Comment: Your response doesn't fit as an answer to what I've asked. Did you not understand something I said? I can try to explain better.